# How to convert a number generated by php into a jQuery counter?

Tags: php, jquery

I have built a simple php visitor counter to count the # of visitors to a site.

```
$count_my_page = (text file);
$hits = file($count_my_page);
$hits[0] ++;
$fp = fopen($count_my_page , "w");
fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
fclose($fp);
echo $hits[0];
```

Instead of boring number showing up, I am trying to turn it into a odometer style jQuery counter or apple style jQuery flip counter.

http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/

How do I take "`$hits[0];`" & transfer it over to jQuery?  I googled extensively but maybe I just don't understand php enough since I came up empty with my search.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a hidden variable

```
<input type="hidden" id="hits" value="<?php echo $hits[0];  ?>" />
```

And access with jquery like this

```
$('#hits').val();
```

Comment: Once again, thank you very much for answering such a newb question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also echo it in the script directly:

```
var hits = '<?php echo $hits[0]; ?>';
```